# Optical software - thin film interference

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, simulations, software, photonics

I am currently using a software called "SCOUT" to thin film interference simulation, and I would like to know if there is a better software to do this type of simulations. My goal is to vary the thickness of a thin film in a multilayer, in order to create interference between the various thin films, and then create a specific color. So I want to freely change the thickness and get a graph of reflectance or transmittance corresponding to that change. The software should allow me to put my own materials with the respective reflectance and transmittance properties.
I know some softwares, like "zemax" and "lumerical" but there are no videos doing what I intend.
Does anyone have suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Ha! It has been almost a decade since I used SCOUT so I couldn’t remember any details but I was going to suggest it 

Answer (score 1):

We are not likely to have advice on relative merits of software at this site. Try stack overflow. But I can give a little advice never the less. You can get a start with pretty much any software. If Scout is free, give it a shot.

This is a common type of filter. You can easily buy one. Google Optical Bandpass Filter.

If you are more interested in the design than having one, google Optical Bandpass Filter Design.

For general info about optical thin film design, the University of Arizona has a very good optics department. They made this available. [Thin Film Optics](https://wp.optics.arizona.edu/winter-school-workshop/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/2015/09/Thin-Film-Optics-Macleod-1.pdf)